# Why open source code at Github isn't matching with the ones provided in package?

Tags: github, flutter

**Screenshot:**

[image]

As you can the code on the left (inside IDE) isn't matching with the one provided on Github, and I am using latest version of the package. **I have highlighted the piece of code I'm referring to.**

---

`pubspec.yaml`

```
in_app_purchase: 0.3.1
```

Here is code [link](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/70d874d15cd20a2f03d1fd4c76cfdfe6c619ec1a/packages/in_app_purchase/lib/src/in_app_purchase/google_play_connection.dart)

Here is the package [link](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase)

Comment: Maybe because the original author did not published it on the pub.dev. If you want to you can always use the package directly from git repo.

Comment: That's generally because the author has not published the latest commits to pub.dev where the package is hosted. Just like @HasilT said, if you want you can directly get the package from github repo.

Comment: @HasilT How can I directly use the package from Github, can you tell me?

Comment: @TahaRushain How can I directly use the package from Github?

Comment: @iKeepChangingName I have that as a answer and also provided the link to the docs that point to the same question. Let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this is because the author didn't push those changes to pub.dev , if you want you can use the package from the github directly by modifying your pubspec.yaml file accordingly, like the following example

```
dependencies:
  plugin1:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/flutter/plugin1.git
```

The above example is taken from [Flutter Docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#dependencies-on-unpublished-packages). In your case, it could be something like

```
dependencies:
  flutter_plugins:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/flutter/plugins.git
```

Or if you only need in_app_purchase and not the entire plugin library then you can do the following

```
dependencies:
  in_app_purchase:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/flutter/plugins.git
      path: packages/in_app_purchase
```

IDE code matches the right-hand side code of OP

[image: Screenshot from the packages in IDE after importing from the repository]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm having errors in using your code, it is `Could not find a file named "plugins/packages/in_app_purchase/pubspec.yaml" in git://github.com/flutter/plugins.git e67c7fa4d4fa6c20c40cf85545f6283467ea12b2.)`

Comment: @iKeepChangingName there was a typo, it will work if you try it now

Comment: Sorry mate, still I am not seeing right hand side code in IDE, did you try it on your own?

Comment: @iKeepChangingName have a look at the screenshot, the right-hand side is there, after importing the package using the Github URL.

Comment: @iKeepChangingName it could be that your packages are cached from the older import, try running `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` using the repo url.

Comment: Thanks, I also tried that, but it is still not working :(